# RxSwift .debounce, .throttle for pagination

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I'm trying to implement pagination. Whenever the table view scrolls, I want the reactor to check if it reached the bottom. But binding `reactor.action` whenever `tableView`'s `didScroll` happens seemed unnecessary.

So I thought it would be better to use an operator to limit binding the `reactor.action`. But I'm not sure which operator is more suitable between `.debounce` and `.throttle` in this case.

```
self.tableView.rx.didScroll
    .skip(1)
    .withLatestFrom(self.tableView.rx.contentOffset)
    .map { [weak self] in
        print("didScroll")
        
        return Reactor.Action.pagination(
            contentHeight: self?.tableView.contentSize.height ?? 0,
            contentOffsetY: $0.y,
            scrollViewHeight: UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        )
    }
    .bind(to: reactor.action)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

I've tried `.debounce` and `.throttle` in my code. But still I'm not sure which one is more suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I always use the `reachedBottom(offset:)` method supplied in [RxSwiftExt](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxSwiftExt/blob/main/Source/RxCocoa/UIScrollView%2BreachedBottom.swift).

That said, on to the answer to the question...

- The `debounce` operator is for when the input is jittery and you want to wait until it settles down to read off the input.
- The `throttle` operator is for when the input is constantly emitting and you want to slow the stream down to a manageable number.
- You can also use `throttle` for when the output will always be the same value (e.g., `()`) and you want to react immediately. In this case, you want to make sure to set `latest` to false.

I'm assuming what you want here is to wait until the user stops scrolling and then check the `y` of the contentOffset (and I expect you already know which to use based on the descriptions above.)

Use `debounce` in this case.

Comment: Do you mean I can use reachedBottom(offset:) method instead of didScroll ?? Or do you mean that I should filter the values I got from the tableView.rx.didScroll with the reachedBottom method?

Comment: You can use it instead. It monitors the `contentOffset` and triggers whenever it transitions from within the offset you set to outside of it, or vice-versa.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!